# Python value error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (732,25,17,33) (25,732,17,33) - coordinates of xarray switched?

Tags: python, metpy

I am trying to calculate the dewpoint temperature with the metpy function metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_specific_humidity(pressure, temperature, specific humidity) from ERA5 gridded data, however I get an error:

```
ds = xarray.open_dataset('/dir/file.nc')
Td = metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_specific_humidity(ds.pressure_level, ds.temperature, ds.specific_humidity)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (732,25,17,33) (25,732,17,33)
```

The shapes are the coordinates of the xarray (time:732, pressure level:25, latitude:17, longitude:33). It seems like the order is switched and the function can´t calculate because of the switched dimensions. Is there a way to fix this?

It would be nice if someone could help me!

Best,
Lena

Comment: What version of MetPy do you have installed? What's the output of `python -c 'import metpy; print(metpy.__version__)'`?

Comment: Thanks for the question! I had the version 1.0 installed. With the newer one I don't have the problem anymore :D so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

(Posting the answer for completeness.) I'm not sure why the data have the dimensions flipped, but with earlier versions of MetPy, we relied strictly on [NumPy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to handle matching up the arrays--which doesn't understand the dimensions, it can only expand the arrays to try to match.
With newer versions of MetPy (I thought 1.0, but certainly > 1.0), it uses [Xarray's broadcasting](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.broadcast.html) which can leverage the named dimensions to align the arrays for operations.